# What does the Y-axis represent in probability density function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

When representing the probability density function, what does the Y-axis represent intuitively? Like, what do the values in the Y-axis mean? Do they have a cardinal meaning or they just represent an ordinal one as in the actual value doesn't matter as much as the value being bigger or smaller than the other values

Comment: I don't think that's the case, the y-axis holds the values of the gradient of the PDF at that point.

Answer (score 0):

The values that the density function takes on are in comparison to the uniform distribution on the space. If the density is larger than 1, you are more likely to find the random variable in that small region than if you had the uniform law. Similarly, if your density is less than 1 at a point, you are less likely to find the random variable in that small region around the point.